# must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .net Core 6
I have search this error but i couldn't find a solution

I have three classes and they are implement each other but while i am starting my APİ
i am getting error from  EfProductDal class. It saying  MyDbContext must be non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor.

-base abstract class

```
 public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> 
        : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
     where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
     where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
  }
```

-IEntityRepository

```
 public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
    {
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
        IList<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }
```

-EfProductDal

```
public class EfProductDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<Product, MyDbContext>, IProductDal
    {

    }
```

MydbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }          
        public DbSet<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
   }
```

Please, correct me, if something wrong. Kind Regards...

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for a [mcve]. Can you please make sure that the code you post can be copied and pasted to show the error you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where TContext : DbContext, new()` says that TContext must have a default c'tor. But `MyDbContext` does not.